# Distance from vector vs distance from projection

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, normed-spaces, geometric-inequalities

Let $x,y,z,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Assume $x^\top w \geq 0$, $y^\top w \geq 0$, $z^\top w = 0$ and $\|x\| = \|y\| = \|z\| = 1$, for a general norm $\|\cdot \|$. Moreover, define $p(x,w)$ to be the projection, with respect to the norm $\|\cdot \|$, of $x$ onto the hyperplane $\{v \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ v^\top w = 0\}$, that is, $p(x,w) \in \arg \min_{v^\top w = 0} \|x-v\|$ [1]. Also, define $z(x,w)$ to be a unit norm vector on the hyperplane which is closest to $x$, that is, $z(x,w) \in \arg \min_{\|v\|=1, \ v^\top w = 0} \|x-v\|$.

I would like to prove the following:

$$
\|x - z(x,w)\| \leq \|y - z(y,w)\| \iff \|x - p(x,w)\| \leq \|y - p(y,w)\| \tag{1}.
$$

In words, if the distance from $x$ to $z(x,w)$ is smaller than the distance from $y$ to $z(y,w)$, so is the distance from $x$ to its projection onto the hyperplane that $z(x,w)$ lies on.

My end goal is to show that $\arg\min_{i = 1,\ldots,N} \|x - z(x,w_i)\| = \arg\min_{i = 1,\ldots,N} \|x - p(x,w_i)\|$, that is, instead of looking for the vector $z(x,w_i)$ closest to $x$, we can actually minimize the distance from the closest hyperplane, which has the closed form solution
$$
\|x - p(x,w)\| = \frac{|x^\top w|}{\|w\|_*},
$$
where $\| \cdot \|_*$ is the dual norm to $\| \cdot \|$ [1].

Also, I pretty sure $(1)$ holds when $\| \cdot \| = \| \cdot \|_2$ (the standard euclidean norm).

My questions are:

- Is (1) true for a general norm?
- If not, does it hold for some special case (other than $\| \cdot \| = \| \cdot \|_2$)? Or for some related problem, for instance, if the projection $p(x)$ is with respect to $\|\cdot \|_*$ instead of $\|\cdot \|$?

[1] Mangasarian, Olvi L. "Arbitrary-norm separating plane." Operations Research Letters (1999).

Comment: I don't think $(1)$ is true for $\|\cdot\| = \|\cdot\|_2$. For example, suppose $w = (0, 1)^\top$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$ (i.e. the hyperplane is the $x$-axis). Let$$x=\left(-\frac{4}{5},\frac{3}{5}\right),\quad y=\left(\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5}\right),\quad z=(1,0)^\top.$$Then$$p(x)=\left(-\frac{4}{5},0\right),\quad q(y)=\left(\frac{3}{5},0\right)$$and$$\|x - p(x)\| = \frac{6}{5} \le \frac{8}{5} = \|y - p(y)\|,$$but$$\|x - z\|=\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}}>\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}=\|y-z\|.$$

Comment: @TheoBendit you are right. Actually, I made a mistake in the original formulation of my problem. I have edited the question to fix it.